# Is there a way to use methods dynamically within a for loop in python?

Tags: python

Is there a way to use methods within a loop in Python? Something like the following:

```
obj=SomePythonObject()
list_of_methods=dir(obj)
for i in list_of_methods:
    try:
        print obj.i()     
    except:
        print i,'failed'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I do variable variables in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-do-variable-variables-in-python) Specifically the second answer.

Comment: This seems potentially dangerous... Better hope that SomePythonObject doesn't have a deleteUsersHardDrive method.

Comment: I understand - just trying out a new Python API that doesn't have good documentation and got bored with trying out all the methods manually. Thanks for pointing it out though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that's possible, use [callable](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#callable) and [getattr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
obj=SomePythonObject()
list_of_methods=dir(obj)
for i in list_of_methods:
    try:
        item = getattr(obj, i, None)
        if callable(item):
            item()     
    except:
        print i,'failed'
```

Comment: "item = getattr(obj, im item)"  im item?